how to acquire camera lens location in gyroscope/IMU coordinates
I'm using Google's Camera2 API and ARCore kit(in differenc scene) recording videos, and receiving IMU data in the same time, I need to know where the camera locates when the IMU detects device rotation.
the doc says it is possible to get lens pos reference/tranform matrix to main camera lens(LENS_POSE_REFERENCE_PRIMARY_CAMERA) or the gyroscope(LENS_POSE_REFERENCE_GYROSCOPE), the latter one is what I want. but this is a non-configurable and read-only characteristics, on my device it returns LENS_POSE_REFERENCE_PRIMARY_CAMERA, therefore I need another solution to get this information.
